# Problems Connecting Canon Powershot to 2015 Macbook Air

Tags: macbook-pro, finder, data-transfer, camera

I have a Canon Powershot G12, and I am attempting to get some files over onto my Macbook Air. This is the first time I attempted to do this, I normally upload them onto my Macbook Pro. But when I do connect it, it shows up as "Remote Disk", and there are no files in the "Remote Disk". Do I have to install a driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need driver & software for your [Canon PowerShot G12](https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/support/details/cameras/support-point-and-shoot/powershot-g-series/powershot-g12).

[image: PowerShot G12 driver support]